# Depend on a branch or tag using a git URL in a package.json?

Tags: git, dependencies, npm, branch, git-tag

Say I've forked a node module with a bugfix and I want to use my fixed version, on a feature branch of course, until the bugfix is merged and released.

How would I reference my fixed version in the `dependencies` of my `package.json`?

Answer (score 669, accepted):

### Solution 1

From the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies), using a git URL:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#<branch>

https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#feature\/<branch>
```

Don't use `git://` protocol for GitHub, it [is not longer supported](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/)

### Solution 2

As of NPM version 1.1.65, you can use a shorten [github URL](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls):

```
<user>/<project>#<branch>
```

Comment: As of npm 1.1.65, Github URL can be more concise `user/project`. https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html You can attach the branch like `user/project#branch`

Comment: `git://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#feature/blah` worked but `<user>/<project>.git#feature/blah` didn't ... perhaps their regex needs to be more advanced to take `feature/blah` into account. This was npm `v1.4.28`

Comment: How do you include version number?

Comment: @hurrymaplelad can I do the same for pull request? If so, how is the command?

Comment: Updated NPM docs link https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Comment: @dantheta this is a bad practice... we don't know if Github will implode 4 years down the line, and Gitlab etc becomes the new default.

Comment: deprecated `git://` More information see: https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#no-more-unauthenticated-git

Comment: For `http` or `https`, you should indicate this points to a Git repository by changing the protocol to `git+http` or `git+https`. ([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json?v=true#git-urls-as-dependencies))

Answer (score 155):

per @dantheta's comment:

> As of npm 1.1.65, Github URL can be more concise user/project. npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html You can attach the branch like user/project#branch

So

```json
"babel-eslint": "babel/babel-eslint",
```

Or for tag v1.12.0 on jscs:

```json
"jscs": "jscs-dev/node-jscs#v1.12.0",
```

Note, if you use npm --save, you'll get the longer git

From https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies

> Git URLs as Dependencies
>
> Git urls are of the form:
>
> `git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli.git#v1.0.27`
> `git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli#semver:^5.0`
> `git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/cli.git`
> `git://github.com/npm/cli.git#v1.0.27`

> If `#<commit-ish>` is provided, it will be used to clone exactly that commit. If > the commit-ish has the format `#semver:<semver>`, `<semver>` can be any
> valid semver range or exact version, and npm will look for any tags or refs
> matching that range in the remote repository, much as it would for a registry
> dependency. If neither `#<commit-ish>` or `#semver:<semver>` is specified, then
> master is used.

> GitHub URLs
>
> As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub urls as just "foo":
> "user/foo-project". Just as with git URLs, a commit-ish suffix can be
> included. For example:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "name": "foo",
>  "version": "0.0.0",
>  "dependencies": {
>    "express": "expressjs/express",
>    "mocha": "mochajs/mocha#4727d357ea",
>    "module": "user/repo#feature\/branch"
>  }
> }
> ```

Comment: Depending on a commit sha1 should be the preferred option, particularly if you depend on a repo that is not under your control. Git branches and tags are not immutable (can be deleted / changed, maliciously / by accident), while it's (nearly) impossible to create a sha1 collision.

Comment: can I have a branch AND a commit for commit-ish?

Comment: what about https git URLs?

Answer (score 55):

If you want to use `devel` or `feature` branch, or you haven’t published a certain package to the NPM registry, or you can’t because it’s a private module, then you can point to a `git://` URI instead of a version number in your `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
   "public": "git://github.com/user/repo.git#ref",
   "private": "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/repo.git#ref"
}
```

The `#ref` portion is optional, and it can be a branch (like `master`), tag (like `0.0.1`) or a partial or full commit id.

Answer (score 28):

On latest version of NPM you can just do:

```bash
npm install gitAuthor/gitRepo#tag
```

If the repo is a valid NPM package it will be auto-aliased in package.json as:

```json
{
  "NPMPackageName": "gitAuthor/gitRepo#tag"
}
```

If you could add this to @justingordon 's answer there is no need for manual aliasing now !

Comment: not, it's not. It installs incorrectly. Somehow it does not include whole directory structure from the repository, only some files like package.json, yarn.lock, readme and license. There is no src or dist folders.

Comment: @StalkAlex https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish and then check the repo you are installing for the build scripts. Maybe they are tagged or the post-install does not work for you, it's an issue for that specific package anyway hope this helps !

Comment: @vortex thanks, what do you mean exactly by tagging? How this makes such problem?

Answer (score 0):

If yo want to use any spesific commit; You can use this

**Template:**

```
github:{UserName}/{RepoName}#{CommitId}
```

**Usage Example in Package.json:**

```
"react": "github:facebook/react#e40893d097f6894b4768d749f796302c57161734"
```

Answer (score -2):

If it helps anyone, I tried everything above (https w/token mode) - and still nothing was working. I got no errors, but nothing would be installed in node_modules or package_lock.json. If I changed the token or any letter in the repo name or user name, etc. - I'd get an error. So I knew I had the right token and repo name.

I finally realized it's because the name of the dependency I had in my package.json didn't match the name in the package.json of the repo I was trying to pull. Even npm install --verbose doesn't say there's any problem. It just seems to ignore the dependency w/o error.