# Efficient way to test a pull request for an npm package dependency

Tags: github, pull-request

I was wondering what the most efficient way is to test a pull request in an npm module?

Imagine the following (quite typical) use case:
- you are using an npm package as a dependency in your project
- you discover a problem, report it and someone offers a fix in a pull request

What is the most effective way to test the pull request without waiting for the pull request to be merged?

I'm aware that I can fork the project, merge any pull request into my fork and then install from my local directory but I was wondering, if there are any more efficient solutions to this typical problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Depend on a branch or tag using a git URL in a package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673/depend-on-a-branch-or-tag-using-a-git-url-in-a-package-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a reffernce to their GitHub repo in your `packages.json` file like:

```
'foo' : 'git://github.com/some_patcher/foo.git#commit_id_that_fixes'
```