# npm package from inside another repo?

Tags: git, npm, walmart-electrode

Related: [Depend on a branch or tag using a git URL in a package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16350673/758177)

The `electrode-archetype-react-app` npm package comes from a subdirectory of another package's git repository: `electrode-io/electrode` → `packages/electrode-archetype-react-app`.

1. How is that possible?
2. How can I hook onto a specific branch of the sub-package?

I tried

```
npm install electrode-io/electrode#electrode-archetype-react-app/some-branch
```

but got the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'electrode-archetype-react-app': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

So then I tried

```
npm install github:electrode-io/electrode#electrode-archetype-react-app/some-branch
npm install github:electrode-io/electrode -- package/electrode-archetype-react-app#some-branch
npm install github:electrode-io/electrode#some-branch -- package/electrode-archetype-react-app
```

No dice

What dark wizardry is this?

**Edit** Thanks to an eagle-eyed colleague: Electrode is using [`Lerna`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), which might be the source of this dark magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed Lerna who was the puppet-master, and it is not possible to use a remote branch from origin. It can only be done locally using a relative path.