# Possible to "npm install" code changes added since last version number change?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This is a n00b npm question, as I'm just getting started here.  Apologies.

I'm using the [node-dbus npm module](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus), whose latest version is 0.2.0.  But I see that there have been code changes (one of which I want) added since the last version number change.

Do I need to ask the author of the package to update the version number so I can easily get the new stuff?  Is it permissible/possible for me to go in and update the version number myself in the github repo?  Or is there some clean way to set up the `dependencies` line in my `package.json` to get the stuff that has been added since the last version number change?

I see that it's supposed to be possible to use a "[git remote url](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)," but so far I'm unable to make that work.  Is that what I should be doing?  Is getting the version number updated the right direction?

Thanks for your help.

Steve

Comment: what  version are you requesting in "package.json?"  ...    "version": "0.2.0", should get u whats committed in the git remote. if npm is not updated to reflect the contents of  git remote , then you can clone the remote and copy that into ./node_modules/$yourPackage directory in the project  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673/depend-on-a-branch-or-tag-using-a-git-url-in-a-package-json

Comment: I am using "^0.20.0", which, because "0.20.0" is the highest version number available, does get me the very first git commit for which the version was set to "0.20.0".  But it does not bring along the newer commits, and thus leaves out the fix that I want.  Yes, I suppose I could clone the github repo, but wouldn't that oblige me to periodically check for updates and pull a new copy from github?  Or maybe I'm not following you.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: check the link, you can code the package.json entry to point to github if u need to .

Comment: Sorry for my mis-statement in the above.  I'm using "^0.2.0", not "^0.20.0".  And yes, the answer below gave me the syntax that I'd somehow failed to find in reading the document earlier.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the official NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you can install a package by:

```
npm install <githubname>/<githubrepo>[#<commit-ish>]
```

In your case, it should be:

```
npm install sidorares/node-dbus#<the-commit-that-contains-your-wanted-code>
```

You can add `--save` to the command to update `package.json` on the fly.

Please be aware that it is not a good practice to install modules from source code directly as it might not be a stable version.

Comment: This works and does what I was looking for.  Thank you for sharing the actual syntax, which I was having trouble coming up with.

Thank you, too, for the reminder that there are risks to this approach.  I suppose that inclines me to think that the **real** answer would be to contact the author and get him to bless the code he's willing to call official by giving it a new version number.