# How to install Gulp v4 with NPM v5?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, gulp, gulp-4

I've installed the new version of npm but now when I try to run the next command the dependency doesn't install:

```
npm i -S gulpjs/gulp#4.0

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for undefined@4.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

NPM Version: v5.0.1

Is there a new way to install npm packages from github branches?

Related question (old NPM version): [Depend on a branch or tag using a git URL in a package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673/depend-on-a-branch-or-tag-using-a-git-url-in-a-package-json)

NPM Docs about install dependencies: [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in v5.0.2

[Related github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16864)