# Typescript bundler to typescript file

Tags: typescript

I know that are some popular javascript bundlers like `webpack` or `rollup`, and I know you can bundle your typescript code to a single javascript file using those bundlers.

What I'm looking for is something similar for typescript files. For example to bundle multiple typescript files into a single typescript file based on the `import .... from` syntax

Do you know if such tool exists?

Comment: For what purpose?
How do you expect the TypeScript output to look like?
I don't understand what is the interest to have TypeScript modules wrapped around IIFEs.
Furthermore, static-only objects like types could not be imported from IIFEs, and are currently scoped to the file (which is the module) context.

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to use namespaces.

Comment: Why would you need that? I cannot think of a scenario where this might make sense.

Comment: I don't think a tool exists, because you don't need it. Simply re-export everything in a new file... you can then import from that that entry file.

Comment: @kube I'm building a library based on typescript that contains around 50 .ts files. This library will have different versions and I want to send this library to some developers to build some apps based on those .ts files. Bundling those files will help a lot. For example : sdk_1.0.ts , sdk_1.1.ts  Every developer will include the right sdk version in his project and will download a single file instead of 50+

Comment: @Meirion Hughes thanks for your reply. What do you mean "re-export everything in a new file" ?

Comment: that isn't a compelling argument: you can simply zip all 50 into a single file.

Comment: in `index.ts` you can do `export * from './my/files/foo.ts` ...etc... , then all you need to do is `import {Foo} from './'`

Comment: Btw... to solve your actual problem: put your library on github (can be private) then have npm install directly from the repo, which stores the ts files. Each developer can explicitly state which branch/tag they want to work off. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673/depend-on-a-branch-or-tag-using-a-git-url-in-a-package-json

Comment: If you want to distribute your library as a single file, bundle it with Webpack, and build the  `.d.ts` definition file.

Comment: Don't forget to expose everything needed by the final user (types, objects and functions) from your Webpack entry point.

Comment: @kube, @Saravana, @Meirion, Another use case where this makes sense is in competitive programming or coding competitions where only a single `.ts` file is accepted but writing all the code in a single file becomes a dev-nightmare. I'd like to have an option to just bundle it into a single `.ts` file without the transpilation or the involvement of `.d.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rollup-plugin-dts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-dts) to bundle your typescript declaration files.

### Usage

Install the package from `npm`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-dts
```

Add it to your `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

const config = [
  // …
  {
    input: "./my-input/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/my-library.d.ts", format: "es" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];

export default config;
```